# Div with height % not collapsing into itself with overflow auto

Tags: html, css

Alright so this is the third time I've looked for help on a particular element I'm working on in an app so I apologize for the repetition.

I'm building a questionnaire for an application and I want all the questions to be contained in a div and the overflow hidden. The problem I'm currently running into is if the height doesn't exceed 80% of the window size the containing div doesn't collapse into itself and there is an unnecessary amount of whitespace left over.

I have tried to switch the questionnaire-box height style to max-height but this caused the overflow content of the .questions div to be hidden instead of scrollable.

I have a strong suspicion I may need to handle this with js but I prefer straight CSS and HTML if possible.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
 }

.questionnaire-container {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .1);
}

.questionnaire-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.questions {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="questionnaire-container">
  <div class="questionnaire-box">
    <div class="questions">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe using max-height, instead of height will work for .questionnaire-box

Comment: Yes, I tried this but unfortunately, it caused another problem where the overflow of .questions was hidden instead of scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the padding from `.questions` to `.questionnaire-box`. Also, `.questions` has no `(...-)width` attributes set anymore, but the `.questionnaire-box`'s `max-width` is `calc(70vh - 2rem)`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moor131j/2/

Comment: Yes I've tried this but the problem is if I use max-height the overflow is hidden and the child div .questions  also hides its content so the scroll no longer works.

Comment: Do you want to keep the bottom padding if the text is too long?

Comment: If the text exceeds the height of 80% I want it to be scrollable within the .questions div. I have an additional div that holds navigation that is positioned absolutely at the bottom so I need to have a little extra space so the content exceeds the navigation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work either because the container with a white background is .questionnaire-box so even if .questions has a max-height the container with the white space will still be at 80% height.

Comment: wow almost works like magic... I do need to do a little bit of formatting in my own app but I think that was it! Do you mind explaining to me what this part does? 

max-height: calc(70vh - 2rem);

Also I noticed you have max-height set twice one to 70% and one to what I just listed above. Do I need to keep both?

Comment: You don't need the first max-height, that was a mistake. calc(70vh - 2rem) is 70% of the window height minus the padding (top + bottom)